# Run Node task/function at specific time daily while accounting for Daylight Savings

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduling

I'm trying to run a Node task/function at a specific time each day (7am Eastern Time) regardless of Daylight Savings.  I've tried cron-based packages, but cron doesn't seem to account for it.  The server the app is running on is on GMT/UTC, so that that needs to be taken into consideration as well.  Here is my current code:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
...
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 12 * * *', function(){
  bot.channels.get(getDefaultChannel().id).send("Hello!  Your daily fact for today is", { embed: generateEmbed(getRandomFact()) });
});
```

This works fine, but since we just moved ahead an hour, the message appears at 8am instead of 7am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one, I've played about with a couple of ways of doing this, I think the Cron library works the best (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). You can schedule a job to run at 7 am in the US/Eastern timezone.

```
"use strict";
var cron = require('cron');

var job1 = new cron.CronJob({
  cronTime: '0 7 * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    bot.channels.get(getDefaultChannel().id).send("Hello!  Your daily fact for today is", { embed: generateEmbed(getRandomFact()) });
  },
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'US/Eastern'
});
```

Comment: Hey @TheIcemanCometh, I've updated the answer here with code that's a little more concise!

Comment: I finally had a chance to take a look a this today, and this looks like it will work nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice one, the Cron job package is very handy!